# Spring Data JPA programmatically enable auditing

Tags: configuration, spring-data-jpa, auditing

How can I do the same as: `<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="yourAuditorAwarebean" />` programmatically in a `@Configuration` class?
Is the spring xml configuration mandatory to do this?

reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e2427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Config for auditing is now supported since Spring Data JPA 1.5 ([link to documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e2562))

Replace the `<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="yourAuditorAwarebean" />` with the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation on any of your configuration class.

E.g:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
class Config {

  @Bean
  public AuditorAware<AuditableUser> yourAuditorAwarebean() {
    return new YourAuditorAwareImpl();
  }
}
```